# Does time pass for your puffles?

Tags: club-penguin

In Club Penguin, if you don't play for, say, a year, will your puffles run away because of neglect?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, honestly, it kinda sucks.

Comment: What if you just don't log in for a year? Would they still run away?